# I need a Windows-compatible, square pixel font

Tags: fonts, pixel-fonts, bitmap-fonts

I'm looking for a square pixel font, preferably 8x8 pixels per character. I would like it to look something like this:

[ibm-style font http://dwarf.lendemaindeveille.com/images/0/0e/CGA8x8thick.png](http://dwarf.lendemaindeveille.com/images/0/0e/CGA8x8thick.png)

I need more or less every character shown here, especially the box drawing ones. The very few Windows fonts I've found after about an hour of searching don't have very few (if any) extended characters.

I'm currently writing a pseudo-roguelike, and I've always preferred square fonts in roguelikes. I can use other methods if I must, but it would make my life a million times easier if a font like this existed.

Again, it needs to be Windows-compatible. It's fine if I need to convert some X11 format into a Windows-compatible one, but I need a link to the tools to do so.

Or, perhaps, somebody knows of a program to easily turn bitmaps into fonts? Because the included image is actually exactly what I want: it looks exactly like older IBM CGA/EGA systems.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dskcenter.free.fr/Download/DskCenter_fonts.zip

The PC_CGA font looks like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of [Windows use to ship with .FON](http://www.melbpc.org.au/pcupdate/9303/9303article3.htm) files (pre-cursor to TTF). The FON's tended to be pretty basic looking. You probably want to find COURIER.FON.

Also, you could [edit your own TTF](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/), or make an existing TTF Monospaced. But you would have to find an editor for that.

Answer (score 0):

Something to look at might be "Proggy Square". One of the versions of that font, the ANSI/Bitmap one, has extended characters. Proggy Square and variants are available around the web at various places. As I understand it, they are free to use.

Comment: Worth noting that your first link (and probably the second one) leads to a spammy page.

Comment: Hrm, the original site seems to have gone down since I posted. I'll remove the links.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.uwe-sieber.de/dosfon_e.html

Go to the bottom of that page.  I did not try them all but the OEM Codepage 850 font seems to be what you want, and the others may work as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, these are not square. :(